# How to adjust border size in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to reduce the border size of the header text such that it fits exactly. I'm using `border: 10px solid;` at the moment.

Here's the fiddle of what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/hy8f989x/

HTML:

```
<div class = "container">

    <div class = "banner bounce">

        <h1 class="banText">Hello!</h1>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.banner {
    font-family: 'Slabo 27px', sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.banText {
    border: 10px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/3O2o342K3O1C1M2P461x/%201920x1080%20Wallpaper.png");
    background-size: 1920px 1080px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

As you can see, the border stretches across the whole screen and what I want is to reduce the breadth/width of the border (not thickness) and fit it perfectly with the text.

Answer (score 2):

Add `display: inline` to .banText

```
.banText {
    border: 10px solid;
    display: inline;
}
```